# The global variable declared in the class in Python

Tags: python, class, global-variables, init

I have this question for quit a while and would like to make sure that I understand it correctly. I am now working on a question on algorithm

> ***Kth Largest Number in a Stream***
>
> Design a class to efficiently find the Kth largest element in a stream of numbers.
>
> The class should have the following two things:
>
> - The constructor of the class should accept an integer array containing initial numbers from the stream and an integer `K`.
> - The class should expose a function `add(int num)` which will store the given number and return the Kth largest number.

The result is:

```
from heapq import *

class KthLargestNumberInStream:
    # minHeap = []

    def __init__(self, _input, _k):
        self.k = _k
        # the update minHeap will keep in the class and won't get cleared
        self.minHeap = []

        # rather than assigning values to input
        # call the add function to add
        for num in _input:
            self.add(num)

    def add(self, num):
        # minHeap is defined outside this function and within the class
        # need to use the self.minHeap to call it
        heappush(self.minHeap, num)
        # return the top k
        if len(self.minHeap) > self.k:
            heappop(self.minHeap)
        # print(self.minHeap)
        return self.minHeap[0]

def main():
    kthLargestNumber = KthLargestNumberInStream([3, 1, 5, 12, 2, 11], 4)
    print("4th largest number is: " + str(kthLargestNumber.add(6)))
    print("4th largest number is: " + str(kthLargestNumber.add(13)))
    print("4th largest number is: " + str(kthLargestNumber.add(4)))


main()
```

The print out the all the elements visited in the min heap is as:

```
[3]
[1, 3]
[1, 3, 5]
[1, 3, 5, 12]
[1, 2, 5, 12, 3]
[1, 2, 5, 12, 3, 11]
[1, 2, 5, 12, 3, 11, 6]
4th largest number is: 1
[1, 2, 5, 12, 3, 11, 6, 13]
4th largest number is: 1
[1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 11, 6, 13, 12]
4th largest number is: 1
```

I am curious that each time we called the `kthLargestNumber = KthLargestNumberInStream([3, 1, 5, 12, 2, 11], 4)`, and why it won't create a new and empty heap and then add values to it, but keep the element from the previous call of the `add` function.

However, in this question [Anther question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65713175/self-defined-class-issue-attributeerror-xx-object-has-no-attribute-xx), the `max_sum` will get reset each time.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You only call `kthLargestNumber  = KthLargestNumberInStream(...)` once.

Comment: " and why it won't create a new and empty heap" Where are you doing this? You only create one `KthLargestNumberInStream` object.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. Does it mean that each time we call `kthLargestNumber.add(`, but it won't call the `KthLargestNumberInStream([3, 1, 5, 12, 2, 11], 4)` again. So that we still have the previous minHeap there? I am still confused about what is going on there. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, @juanpa.arrivillaga. I think I called the `kthLargestNumber.add` each time. Will it create a new minHeap? Thanks.

Comment: No, you only get a new heap when you create a new object by calling `KthLargestNumberInStream`. Each object gets its own heap and retains it.

Comment: @QiangSuper no, why would it? You should read the [official tutorial on classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: Note, **there is no global variable defined in `KthLargestNumberInStream`**

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar. `kthLargestNumber` is a variable than a function itself. So when I call `kthLargestNumber.add`, I only add value to the existing heap.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga. Does self.minHeap work like a global variable? I don''t need to call `global minHeap` here.

Comment: Thanks for sharing @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @QiangSuper no, `self.minHeap` is an *instance variable*. Again you **really must** read [the basics of classes in python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) or else it's just going to be confusion on top of confusion. Why are you trying to write classes without the fundamentals in the first place?

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. Switched from R so have no ideas about the class. I am going to read the article first.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga. I am going to go through this article. Switched from R and prepare the interviews.